# If $x>0$, then find the greatest value of the expression $ \frac{x^{100}}{1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{200}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

> If $x>0$, then find the greatest value of the expression $ \dfrac{x^{100}}{1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{200}}$

This expression simplifies to $ \frac{(x^{100})(x-1)}{x^{200}-1}$ using sum of n terms of GP. Now one can find the maxima by equating the derivative to zero. But is there any other way not involving calculus to get the maximum value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: write it as

$$
\begin{align}
& \quad \frac{1}{\cfrac{1}{x^{100}} + \cfrac{1}{x^{99}} + \cdots + \cfrac{1}{x} + 1 + x + \cdots + x^{99} + x^{100}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \left(x+\cfrac{1}{x}\right) + \left(x^2+\cfrac{1}{x^2}\right) + \cdots +  \left(x^{100}+\cfrac{1}{x^{100}}\right)}
\end{align}
$$

and use the fact that $a+\frac{1}{a} \ge 2$ for $a \gt 0$, with equality iff $a=1$.

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice :)

Comment: @Ovi Thank you. In the end, it's still like applying AM-GM for $n=2$ a hundred times vs. applying it once for $n=201$, but with slightly fewer intermediate computations in the former. Credit that to laziness ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Using AM-GM at the denominator $\geq 201 ( {\displaystyle \prod_{i =0}^{200} x^i} )^{1/201} $ thus you get denominator is always more than $201 \cdot x^{100}$ thus the max value is $\frac{1}{201} $ at $1$ you can also use graphs to see that.

Comment: Can you just elaborate on the am-gm part

Comment: oh okay I get it. Thank you :)

Comment: $x>0$ so i used am-gm

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1

Answer (score 1):

AM-GM inquelity $=>$
$$
\\1+x+\cdots+x^{2n}\geq (2n+1)(x^{0+1+\cdots+2n})^{1/{2n}}=(2n+1){x^{\frac{2n+1}{2}}}
\\f(x)=\frac{x^n}{1+x+\cdots+x^{2n}}\leq\frac{x^n}{(2n+1){x^{\frac{2n+1}{2}}}}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)\sqrt{x}}
\\
\\\max_{x>0}(f(x))=\frac{1}{(2n+1)\sqrt{x}}
$$
then $f(x)=\frac{1}{(2n+1)\sqrt{x}}\>$ if and only if $x=1$
$$\\$$
ANSWER $\>\frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{201}\>$.
(Sorry english my second language)

Comment: What is the point of repeating an answer that was posted almost two years ago?